# What is the term for “assembly-able”?

Tags: word-request

The context is like: “This table from IKEA comes in parts and thus ‘assembly-able’”

Meaning it can be assembled and disassembled. We have the term in my native language, literally “assemble-disassemble”.

Comment: Is that the exact text? Because "assembly-able" seems like it should mean "can be made into an assembly."  Anyway, what is your question?

Comment: Would it be something like 组装拆卸 in your language?  Maybe it is assemblable  可组装 ?

Comment: I don't think we have an adjective meaning "assemblable". It's often called "_flat-pack_ furniture" or  "furniture _for self-assembly_."

Comment: I actually don't see a problem with *assemblable*, and it is out there in live usage: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=assemblable

Comment: @Dan my language is Indonesian. If assemblable is a word then perhaps that's what I'm looking for. I tried to google assembly-able but can't find any good match. But the assemblable has some definition I think what I'm looking for.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian thank you for the reply. If we're talking about a hydraulic system, is "hydraulic system for self-assembly" considered proper usage for the term?

Comment: @stangdon yes. I never read the word assemblable, and did not show up when I look up about assembly-able. I think that's what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: A hydraulic system? I thought we were at Ikea! Try [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/371656/does-english-allow-assemblable-to-be-created-from-assemble)

Comment: @OldBrixtonian yes, it was to generalize things. In my native language, the term for assemblable for things like furniture and hydraulic system, and many other things that can be assembled, is the same. But now I see that that is misleading in this kind of question after I saw a comment mentioning "flat-pack furniture", which certainly can't be applied to hydraulic system. Sorry.

Comment: @Chen Li Yong: It's fine :-) Did you look at that link? People there seem to think 'assemblable' is acceptable. (Or acceptablable!)

Comment: _Assemblable_ is an uncommon word (my spellchecker doesn't recognise it!) but words ending in '-able' normally start with a verb, not a noun.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian yes I already look at it. It reaffirms that assemblable is indeed acceptablable  Thanks!

Comment: @KateBunting yes my spellchecker also highlight this as wrong. but it's okay I think. Btw is assemble actually a noun?

Comment: No, it's a verb, but _assembly_ is a noun (and therefore not suitable for making such a word).

Comment: @KateBunting I see. Thanks for the explanation!